# Javascript ES6 class inheritance static property

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, methods, ecmascript-6

I have some ES6 classes with inheritance.

The base class has some methods which are inherited to all child classes.
Problem: these methods use static arrays specific to the child classes.

Each child class has an individual "add" method to address the different params.

Now I don't know how I can use the methods with each individual static array property.
As the methods are the same for each child class, I don't want to duplicate the code in each child class if possible.

Some ideas how to solve this?

Code:

```
class Model extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.id = Math.max(...Model.all.map(item => item.id + 1), 1) 
    }

    static all = [];    // All items

    // Problem: 'Model.all' hereunder is wrong because this array does not exist in child classes.
    // Instead, each child class has its own static array 'all'.

    get(id){
        var found;

        Model.all.forEach(item => {     
            if(item.id == id){ found = item; }
        });
        return found;
    }

    change(id, property, newValue){
        let obj = this.get(id);
        let index = Model.arr.indexOf(obj);

        obj[property] = newValue;
        Model.arr.splice(index, 1, obj);
        return obj; 
    }

    remove(id){
        let obj = this.get(id);
        let index = Model.arr.indexOf(obj);

        return Model.arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

class Risk extends Model {
    constructor(criteria, weight, rating, comment){
        super();
        this.add(criteria, weight, rating, comment);
    }

    static all = [];

    add(criteria, weight, rating, comment){
        Risk.all.push({
            criteria,
            weight,
            rating,
            comment,
            result: this.rating * 3,
            id: Math.max(...Risk.all.map(risk => risk.id + 1), 1) 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, found a solution. I just add a param 'arr' to each of the methods in the base class.

class method:
get(id, arr){
  var found;
 
  arr.forEach(item => {
   if(item.id == id){ found = item; }
  });
  return found;
 }

let risk = new Risk('Bla');
risk.get(1, Risk.all); // Returns risk object with id == 1

Comment: This is just why you shouldn't use static mutable arrays to keep your instance data.

Comment: @Bergi So you suggest to make an array of objects somewhere else, let's say in an app object? I had this idea, but I am not sure what is better practice.

Comment: Yes, if it is for storing instances of `Model`… On the other hand, I'm not sure what you are doing here at all, it might be more sensible to just make the `arr` an instance property (not a `static` one) of each `Model`. Replace each `Model.arr` by `this.arr`, and the `Risk` would probably become a `new Model(…)` (instead of a subclass)

Comment: One issue is that I want to set an unique id for each subclass object. So every time an object is created via 'new ...()', this object should get an id by using Math.max(...arr.map(item => item.id + 1), 1). How could I do that without a static array?

Comment: As I said, don't use subclasses at all. You're not creating objects with `new`, you appear to create them with `add`. Your models are collections, not model classes.